# Class property and table column mapping issue (Symfony 5 with Doctrine)

Tags: php, symfony, pdo, doctrine-orm

I am pretty new to Symfony and Doctrine and encountered this strange issue:

I have the following db column names:
[table schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVXHc.png)

I have the following entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\InternApplicationRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="intern_applications")
 */
class InternApplication
{
    const RECORD_CREATED = 0;
    const RECORD_SENT = 1;
    const RECORD_ERROR = -1;
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="listing_id", type="integer")
     */
    private $listingId;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="listing_name", type="string", length=80)
     */
    private $listingName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="listing_emp_mail", type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $listingEmployerMail;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="fname", type="string", length=25)
     */
    private $fName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="lname", type="string", length=25)
     */
    private $lName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=25)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="phone", type="string", length=15, nullable=true)
     */
    private $phone;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="linkedin_url", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     */
    private $linkedInUrl;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="cv_filename", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     */
    private $cvFilename;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="integer")
     */
    private $status;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="string")
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="string")
     */
    private $updatedAt;
```

And a repository method which generates the instance of an entity above:

```
    use App\Entity\InternApplication;
    use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
    use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
    use Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Connection;
    use PDO;

    class InternApplicationRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository

{
    /** @var Connection */
    private $conn;

    public function __construct(
        ManagerRegistry $registry,
        Connection $connection
    ) {
        $this->conn = $connection;
        parent::__construct($registry, InternApplication::class);
    }

    public function getApplicationById(int $id): InternApplication
        {
            $items = $this->conn->executeQuery(
                'select * from intern_applications where id = :id',
                ['id' => $id]
            )->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, InternApplication::class);
            
            return 1 === count($items) ? $items[0] : null;
        }
```

When the repository method is called I end up having this object (**** is used to hide the actual data):

```
    AdminInternApplicationsController.php on line 80:
App\Entity\InternApplication {#1263 ▼
  -id: "89"
  -listingId: null
  -listingName: null
  -listingEmployerMail: null
  -fName: null
  -lName: null
  -email: "****@gmail.com"
  -phone: "****"
  -linkedInUrl: null
  -cvFilename: null
  -status: "1"
  -createdAt: null
  -updatedAt: null
  +"listing_id": "195"
  +"listing_name": "Doloremque qui lab"
  +"listing_emp_mail": "****@gmail.com"
  +"f_name": "****"
  +"l_name": "****"
  +"linkedin_url": "https://www.linkedin.com/in/****"
  +"cv_filename": ""
  +"created_at": "2021-08-05 16:11:29"
  +"updated_at": "2021-08-05 16:11:33"
}
```

As you may see, the public fields are being generated instead of filling the private ones. It seems that even though there are @orm\column calls inside my entity, orm fails to map my snake_case table column names to camelCases class properties. Any thoughts?

Comment: Why do you use `$this->conn` to gather data? Why not use the repository through Doctrine's own stuff?

Comment: You seem to be confusing Doctrine's ORM layer with Doctrine's Database Abstraction Layer(DBAL).  The DBAL is basically a thin wrapper over PDO and when you query with it you get the actual database column information.  No ORM mapping.  Just do a $internApp = $internRepo->find($id) to get the actual app entity.